# Anyone manage to work entity metadata wrapper with profile2 entity?

Tags: 7, users, entities

Code:

```
$profile = profile2_load_by_user($account);
$profile = $profile['main'];

$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('profile2_type', $profile);

$wrapper->field_first_name->set(devel_generate_word(mt_rand(6, 12)));
```

I'm sure that `$profile` is Profile object. Beside 'profile2_type' I tried 'profile', 'profile2' but got error too.

Current error:

> Unknown data property field_first_name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$profile = profile2_load_by_user($account);
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('profile2', $profile);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `profile2_load_by_user()` returns an array of all user profiles by default, whereas `entity_metadata_wrapper()` needs a single entity object.

Try loading a single profile:

```
$profile = profile2_load_by_user($account, 'profile_name');
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('profile2', $profile);
$wrapper->field_first_name->set(devel_generate_word(mt_rand(6, 12)));
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if something changed since '15, but I had to make an adjustment to the accepted answer to get this to work for a specific profile, e.g., presuming `profile2_type` is the machine name of a defined profile:

```
$profile = profile2_load_by_user($account, 'profile2_type');
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('profile2', $profile->pid);
```

Or, alternatively:

```
$profile = profile2_load_by_user($account);
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('profile2', $profile['profile2_type']->pid);
```

Note the specific reference to the profile ID.

Answer (score 0):

$profile = profile2_load_by_user($user->uid,'profile_type');this will declare a single object from the logged in user